# Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"

Tags: instantiation, classnotfoundexception, fatal-error

I have checked all files in my project and checked all the stackoverflow but didn't find the solution for my project.

This is my error occured again & again.
Checked all the stackoverflow solution but no solution is helpfull

```
E/LoadedApk: Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~T-OQgCyVny3egV3SWr6WIA==/com.youth4work.optimalsoftech-3kem8w4hyJtPzZxNaOhq_w==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~T-OQgCyVny3egV3SWr6WIA==/com.youth4work.optimalsoftech-3kem8w4hyJtPzZxNaOhq_w==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createAppFactory(LoadedApk.java:267)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:990)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:1080)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1335)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:3045)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:3037)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6928)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:254)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2184)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:344)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8212)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:584)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1034)
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to open dex files from /data/app/~~T-OQgCyVny3egV3SWr6WIA==/com.youth4work.optimalsoftech-3kem8w4hyJtPzZxNaOhq_w==/base.apk because: Bad encoded_array value: Failure to verify dex file '/data/app/~~T-OQgCyVny3egV3SWr6WIA==/com.youth4work.optimalsoftech-3kem8w4hyJtPzZxNaOhq_w==/base.apk': Bad encoded_value method type size 7
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:371)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:113)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:86)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:438)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:397)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:166)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:160)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:130)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:146)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:106)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:117)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:127)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoaderWithSharedLibraries(ApplicationLoaders.java:62)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:986)
                ... 14 more
V/GraphicsEnvironment: ANGLE Developer option for 'com.youth4work.optimalsoftech' set to: 'default'
V/GraphicsEnvironment: Neither updatable production driver nor prerelease driver is supported.
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.youth4work.optimalsoftech, PID: 15818
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.youth4work.optimalsoftech.PrepApplication package com.youth4work.optimalsoftech: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.youth4work.optimalsoftech.PrepApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~T-OQgCyVny3egV3SWr6WIA==/com.youth4work.optimalsoftech-3kem8w4hyJtPzZxNaOhq_w==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~T-OQgCyVny3egV3SWr6WIA==/com.youth4work.optimalsoftech-3kem8w4hyJtPzZxNaOhq_w==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1401)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7003)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:254)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2184)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:344)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8212)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:584)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1034)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.youth4work.optimalsoftech.PrepApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~T-OQgCyVny3egV3SWr6WIA==/com.youth4work.optimalsoftech-3kem8w4hyJtPzZxNaOhq_w==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~T-OQgCyVny3egV3SWr6WIA==/com.youth4work.optimalsoftech-3kem8w4hyJtPzZxNaOhq_w==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:76)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1192)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1393)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7003) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:254) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2184) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:344) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8212) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:584) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1034) 
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to open dex files from /data/app/~~T-OQgCyVny3egV3SWr6WIA==/com.youth4work.optimalsoftech-3kem8w4hyJtPzZxNaOhq_w==/base.apk because: Bad encoded_array value: Failure to verify dex file '/data/app/~~T-OQgCyVny3egV3SWr6WIA==/com.youth4work.optimalsoftech-3kem8w4hyJtPzZxNaOhq_w==/base.apk': Bad encoded_value method type size 7
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:371)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:113)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:86)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:438)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:397)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:166)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:160)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:130)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:146)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:106)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:117)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:127)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoaderWithSharedLibraries(ApplicationLoaders.java:62)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:986)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:1080)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1335)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:3045)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:3037)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6928)
E/AndroidRuntime:       ... 9 more
```

this error shown again and again

This is my **Build.gradle(app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.fernandocejas.frodo'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    defaultPublishConfig "debug"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.youth4work.optimalsoftech"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 32
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 7
        versionName "Y4W-optimalsoftech-1.0.6"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('keystore/youth4work_second_key')
            keyAlias 'youth4work_second_key_alias'
            keyPassword "youth4work"
            storePassword "youth4work"
        }

        debug {
            storeFile file('keystore/debug.keystore')
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            storePassword 'android'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
//            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            ndk {
                abiFilters = []
                abiFilters.addAll(ABI_FILTERS.split(';').collect{it as String})
            }
        }

        debug {
            versionNameSuffix "Debug"
            debuggable true
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'
    final RELEASE_VERSION = '1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:18.0.2'
    // Support Libraries
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.5.0'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'
    implementation 'com.malinskiy:materialicons:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.38.0'
    implementation 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.1.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.2.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.2.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.3'
    implementation 'com.github.kevinsawicki:timeago:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.joanzapata.iconify:android-iconify-fontawesome:2.2.2'
    implementation 'com.github.jakob-grabner:Circle-Progress-View:1.2.8'
    implementation 'com.github.vlonjatg:progress-activity:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4'
    implementation 'com.daasuu:animateHorizontalProgressBar:0.2.2'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.3.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.trello:rxlifecycle:0.6.1'
    implementation 'com.trello:rxlifecycle-components:0.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.grennis:ExpandableRecyclerView:0.9.3'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:3.1.0'
    implementation('com.mikepenz:fastadapter:1.4.4@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:fastadapter-extensions:1.5.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.1.0'
    //The tiny Materialize library used for its useful helper classes
    //  compile 'com.mikepenz:materialize:0.8.8@aar'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    testImplementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:3.11.0'
    implementation "com.github.mklimek:ssl-utils-android:$RELEASE_VERSION"
    //implementation 'in.hourglass.mathrender:katexmathview:1.0.2'
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0"
    //implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'

    //For Google pay
    implementation 'com.shreyaspatil:EasyUpiPayment:2.0'

    //for slide show
    implementation 'com.github.denzcoskun:ImageSlideshow:0.1.0'


   compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
   // implementation project(':commonlib')
 //   implementation project(':mobilertc')
}

// Log out test results to console
tasks.matching { it instanceof Test }.all {
    testLogging.events = ["failed", "passed", "skipped"]
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

This is my **Build.gradle(project level)**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.20'
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        mavenCentral()
        maven {url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'}
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.7.1'
        classpath 'me.tatarka.retrolambda.projectlombok:lombok.ast:0.2.3.a2'
        classpath "com.fernandocejas.frodo:frodo-plugin:0.8.3"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
    configurations.classpath.exclude group: 'com.android.tools.external.lombok'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
```

I am stuck in this problem since two days, please help me anyone if know this..